# How to make python interprets foo a b c as foo('a','b','c')

Tags: python

I am new to python and used to MATLAB command window's auto interpretation.

Is there anyway I can make Python interpreter interpret

```
>>> foo a b c
```

as

```
>>> foo('a','b','c')
```

PS, I do know about user input and parsing but I want the python shell/IDLE/console/interpreter to understand this.

Comment: From where are you getting `foo a b c`

Comment: You'll have to learn the syntax of the environment. Sorry.

Comment: That's not really how the interpreter works. I suppose you could try to develop your own version however that would very likely include typing a lot more than set of parens and a few commas.

Comment: as `a` ist not defined, python will not know what to do with it. how should the interperter know the difference between the variable `a` and the string `"a"` if it were not for the quotes...

Comment: Even if you do manage to get the Python interpreter to accept MATLAB syntax, all you'll be doing is writing MATLAB programs in Python, which not only seems pointless (why not just use MATLAB?) but will result in inferior Python programs that other Python coders won't understand.

Answer (score 2):

[IPython](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html) might provide the closest solution. From the manual:

You can do (after enabling it with the %autocall magic command)

```
In [1]: callable_ob arg1, arg2, arg3
```

which is equivalent to

```
callable_ob(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

This is not possible in the regular python interpreter or scripts however.

Comment: Or without that setting, `/callable_ob arg1, arg2, arg3`